# BroadcastReceiver in order to pass data from another Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

Let's say I have MainActivity where are few Fragments in ViewPager. I want to pass data from another Activity to one of these fragments. I'm doing this by BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private MyFragmentReceiver mReceiver;

    public MyFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mReceiver = new MyFragmentReceiver();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("fragmentUpdater"));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // My code here
    }

    public class MyFragmentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //My methods
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mReceiver != null)
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

So in my AnotherActivity I'm doing something like this:

```
Intent data = new Intent("fragmentUpdater");
MyApplication.getInstance().getMainActivity().sendBroadcast(data);
```

Where MyApplication is singleton which contains MainActivity. 
I noticed that BroadcastReceiver is putting something into logs, and I am wondering is that the best way to do it.

1. Are there better ways to pass data from another activity to specific Fragment or call methods in that Fragment?
2. Do I have to include something in AndroidManifest.xml related to BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: you can do it using `LocalBroadcastManager ` instead of `BroadcastReceiver ` for internal components communication

Comment: yup should go that way  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

Comment: But the way I do it is a good way ?

Comment: You could set up an interface between your activity and fragments. I can post an example if you're interested.

Comment: I am very interested :)

Comment: @Nominalista I posted a basic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is using an interface for communicating between your activity and fragments. Example:

**Interface**

```
public interface MyInterface {

    void setSomeValue(int someValue);
    int getSomeValue();

}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface {

    private int someValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // do the usual stuff
    }

    // implement from MyInterface
    @Override
    public void setSomeValue(int someValue) {
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }

    // implement from MyInterface
    @Override
    public int getSomeValue() {
        return someValue;
    }

}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private MyInterface mi;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mi = (MyInterface) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mi.setSomeValue(20);
        int someValue = mi.getSomeValue();

    }

}
```

You can use the interface to communicate between one or more activities, multiple fragments, views, tasks, services, etc etc etc. If you were to go this route, I would create a base activity which implements MyInterface and its methods, and have all other activities extend the base activity. I would even create a base fragment which calls onAttach(), and have all my other fragments extend this base fragment (so that I don't need to call onAttach() in every fragment).

**UPDATE...**

A base fragment would simply look like this:

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    public MyInterface mi;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mi = (MyInterface) context;
    }

}
```

Now, MyFragment would just extend BaseFragment...

```
public class MyFragment extends BaseFragment {
    ...
}
```

There's no need now to attach or even declare MyInterface in any fragment extending BaseFragment, the base fragment already has a public instance of it. You just set/get/etc via your interface without any additional fuss:

```
mi.setSomeValue(20);
```

Comment: MainActivity creates Fragment1 and SecondActivity creates Fragment2. I want to pass data or call method from Fragment2 to Fragment1. But using your code (if I understand it correctly) Fragment2 gets SecondActivity in onAttach method.

Comment: Yes, that's why setting your app up with a base activity which implements the interface, and a base fragment to attach the interface to, would be the way to go. Once you've got that, you can pass any data from/to any class. If done properly, you don't even need to pass around any Bundle data between fragments.

Answer (score 1):

I would use LocalBroadcastManager instead, it gives you the following advantages :

- You know that the data you are broadcasting won't leave your app, so
  don't need to worry about leaking private data.
- It is not possible for other applications to send these broadcasts
  to your app, so you don't need to worry about having security holes
  they can exploit.
- It is more efficient than sending a global broadcast through the system.

This is directly from the official [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Answer (score -1):

You may pass the data using Extras.

Intent data = new Intent("fragmentUpdater");
 data.putExtra("STRING_YOU_NEED", strName);

and you can get the data inside onReceive function by :

String data_needed_here= extras.getString("STRING_YOU_NEED");

Comment: I know that, but the question is is there better methods to passing data than broadcastreceiver

Comment: You don't need to write a Broadcast Receiver. You can simply check if getIntent().getExtras is returning any data inside viewCreated and store if there is value